# Tic-Tac-Toe board output

Tags: java, arrays, ascii-art

I was doing a Tic Tac Toe game assignment but my board did not turn out as I want it to. I am attaching a picture of how I want my board to like along with the part of the code I need help with.

[image]

I think the error is in this part of the code:

```java
public void printBoard() {
    char a = 'A';
    char b = 'B';
    char c = 'C';

    System.out.println("     1   2   3  ");
    System.out.println("  ");

    for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0)
            System.out.print(" " + a + ' ');
        else if (i == 1)
            System.out.print(" " + b + ' ');
        else if (i == 2)
            System.out.print(" " + c + ' ');

        for (int j = 0; j < board[i].length; ++j) {
            System.out.print("|");
            System.out.print(" " + board[i][j] + ' ');

            if (j + 1 == board[i].length)
                System.out.println("|");
        }

        System.out.println("   |---|---|---|");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: So I ran your code and it working fine. The board you show in your image isnt really possible with the normal console I think. But Im not sure whats wrong with your code

Comment: yeah I just wanted to make it as same as my teacher's output. I'll just show what I have and work on it if he says it's not good enough. thank you.

Comment: You are welcome. But I think he will be fine with it. If he shows you how to do his version, please tell me. Im curious

Comment: Sure, you can have nice output in a console!  Use dashes, plus symbol and pipe.  Add an extra row of dashes/plus symbols in-between each row.  Something like [example tic-tac-toe output](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1sIdNfxwuYIyJRHfv6EoMVvmaYj5DDnXx/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Please mention how the board array is defined.

Comment: will do! enjoy your day/night

Comment: Will you show some example output as text in your question? And then explain how it is different than what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Looks fine to me.

```java
public static void main(String... args) {
    char[][] board = {
            { ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ' },
            { ' ', ' ', ' ' }
    };

    printBoard(board);
}

public static void printBoard(char[][] board) {
    assert board != null;
    assert board.length == 3 && board[0].length == 3 && board[1].length == 3 && board[2].length == 3;

    System.out.println("     1   2   3  ");
    System.out.println("   |---|---|---|");

    for (char row = 0, rowName = 'A'; row < 3; row++, rowName++) {
        System.out.print(" " + rowName);

        for (int col = 0; col < board[row].length; col++)
            System.out.print(" | " + board[row][col]);

        System.out.println(" |");
        System.out.println("   |---|---|---|");
    }

    System.out.println();
}
```

**Output:**

```
     1   2   3  
   |---|---|---|
 A |   |   |   |
   |---|---|---|
 B |   |   |   |
   |---|---|---|
 C |   |   |   |
   |---|---|---|
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [*Box-drawing characters*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box-drawing_character) to print something like this:

[image: output image]

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    char[][] board = {
            {'X', ' ', ' '},
            {' ', 'X', ' '},
            {' ', ' ', 'O'}};
    printBoard(board);
}
```

```java
public static void printBoard(char[][] board) {
    System.out.println("    1   2   3");
    System.out.println("  ┌───┬───┬───┐");
    System.out.println("A │ "
            + board[0][0] + " │ "
            + board[0][1] + " │ "
            + board[0][2] + " │ ");
    System.out.println("  ├───┼───┼───┤");
    System.out.println("B │ "
            + board[1][0] + " │ "
            + board[1][1] + " │ "
            + board[1][2] + " │ ");
    System.out.println("  ├───┼───┼───┤");
    System.out.println("C │ "
            + board[2][0] + " │ "
            + board[2][1] + " │ "
            + board[2][2] + " │ ");
    System.out.println("  └───┴───┴───┘");
}
```

Output:

```
    1   2   3
  ┌───┬───┬───┐
A │ X │   │   │ 
  ├───┼───┼───┤
B │   │ X │   │ 
  ├───┼───┼───┤
C │   │   │ O │ 
  └───┴───┴───┘
```